# Webform save draft after each field update

Tags: 7, forms, ajax, webforms

I need to save a draft of the webform after each field change. I know that you can save a draft by clicking a button (or between pages in multi-page forms) and my initial tough was to do a form_alter, add an ajax callback to fields and call the submit handler for save_draft. Had anyone tried something like this?

Some conditions:

- If there is an existing draft for the current user, it needs to update that one (not create a new one);
- it needs to work for anonymous users as well.

Drupal 7 + Webform 7.x-3.x

I'll post the answer here if I manage to do it, but any feedback would be appreciated if there are people who've done this before.

Comment: This should probably go to the [Webform Issues Queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/webform).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found this http://drupal.org/node/1319926 and based on it I've managed to make it work. This is my ajax callback (it can be attached using hook_form_alter(), based on your needs):

```
function _my_module_js_draft($form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
  $draft_sid = _webform_fetch_draft_sid($form['#node']->nid, $user->uid);

  $form_state['values']['details']['sid'] = $draft_sid;
  $form_state['values']['op'] = !empty($form['actions']['draft']['#value']) ? $form['actions']['draft']['#value'] : t('Save Draft');

  $form_state['save_draft'] = TRUE;
  webform_client_form_pages($form, $form_state);
  webform_client_form_submit($form, $form_state);

  return $form;
}
```

For having the save draft functionality available for Anonymous I've used this patch: http://drupal.org/node/1932560#comment-7185674

Comment: Could you provide some more detail about how you attached it using hook_form_alter?

Comment: to your form item array add something like (sorry, I can't make this format the code correctly):

`'#ajax' => array( //save draft callback
                  'callback' => '_my_module_js_draft',
                  'event' => 'click',
                  'validate_first' => FALSE, //run the request even if validations fails
                  'progress' => array(
                    'type' => 'none',
                    'message' => '',
                  ),
                ),`