# webform save draft after each field update - ajax error for anonymous user

Tags: forms, ajax, webforms

I wanted to save webform's draft after each field's update, and i did it with help of this post: [Webform save draft after each field update](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/65851/webform-save-draft-after-each-field-update) .

But it is only working for logged in user, if i try it with anonymous i get ajax error

"An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally.
Debugging information follows.
Path: /system/ajax
StatusText: n/a"

Does anybody have any idea why is this happening? thank you ..

Answer (score 1):

The save draft functionality has not yet been committed for webform for anonymous users.

According to the post you mentioned, @Stefan in his answer claims he added the functioanlity by incorporating my patch from this [issue](https://drupal.org/node/1932560#comment-7185674). (We are testing an updated patch which will be posted to the issue cue within the next couple of days.)

Comment: But is this why i am getting ajax error? My request doesn't reach the part of the code you are talking about.

Comment: @gregab - how do you know your request doesn't reach it? xdebug? If so, where exactly does it fail?

Comment: yes, i set a breakpoint in server-side function, called by ajax and it doesn't reach it. I don't know where it fails, becouse there is no good error message. Javascript ajax function gets called and that's it.

Comment: Nobody knows what it could be?